# How to get nested value as a field in jasper report that uses JSON data source

Tags: json, jasper-reports, datasource

I am using JSON data source for report. I try to create image element and give its expression base64 string. It is in second level of JSON but because of report query Jasper shows first level as a field. For example the query is `product` level and Jasper shows only `name` and `price` as fields. I want to give `logo` field in `someObject` but i can not reach that level. I can not use subreports, my working environment does not allow me to do it. So how can i reach to field get that value ?

```
{
    "product": {
            "name": "Oreo",
            "price": "$1.25",
            "someObject": {
                    "logo": "Base64 string"
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually set the JSON expression for the field to something like:

```
<jasperReport...>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[product]]>
    </queryString>
    ...
    <field name="someObjectLogo" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="someObject.logo"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Some Object Logo]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    ...
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Thank for replying, it is visible in the fields now but value returns null. I tried some short string in text field and returned null.

Comment: I fixed it, I used wrong data adapter and it's working thanks for your help.